# How to compose routes in actor's receive with runRoute?

Tags: scala, akka, actor, spray

I need to add a few custom system messages processing to `spray.routing.HttpService`. I need to chain `receive` methods as follows:

```
def receive = {
 case ...my messages here
 case _ => ...call httpReceive below
}

def httpReceive = runRoute...
```

How to organize this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in Spray `runRoute` converts your route structure into Akka's `Receive`, which is a type alias for `PartialFunction[Any, Unit]`. So if you have some method which handles your own messages and some route you can just compose them with `orElse`:

```
def httpReceive: Receive = runRoute(...)
def handle: Receive = ...

def receive = handle orElse httpReceive
```

Now if your messages will be handled with `handle` method and then, if it was a request, spray will handle this request